# how to use handler with videoview

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-videoview

i'm learning about android multithreading on my own and am using this powerpoint as a main resource: http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter13-MultiThreading.pdf

i am attempting the Handler post approach. on slide 38, it mentions that there needs to be a foreground runnable and a background runnable.

if i want my foreground runnable to be a videoview, would i need to put all my videoview code in a try/catch? or is creating the videoview itself creating a foreground runnable on its own?
is there another way to go about this?

i appreciate any help at all as i'm pretty new to java and android.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you do not need a Handler or to handle your own threading to use a VideoView.

Comment: i'm trying to have a timer working in the background while a video is being played. then at the middle of the video, i want the timer to stop and toast in front of the videoview/stop the videoview. would a handler work for this purpose? i think there may be a way to do this without threading, but i want to learn how multithreading works with this mini project.

Comment: Yes, a Handler would be a good fit for this. Implement a runnable that does the stopping/toasting and then make a handler post that runnable after 1/2 the duration of the video.

Comment: Thanks! so i think that means i need to make my videoview a Runnable in order to have a handler post my timer runnable? (i'm looking at the code on slide 39 on the link i posted as reference)

Comment: No your VideoView is not a runnable. The runnable is the delayed task you want to execute later (the toasting/stopping)

Comment: I've added an answer! Hope it goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `Handlers`/`Threads` to implement a `VideoView` at all - this should run on the UI thread just like normal views.

From your comments though I understand this is a learning exercise, so you can implement a `Runnable` task that performs what you need it to do. It's not really related to your `VideoView`, just something you want to execute seperately.

For example:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HELLO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        videoView.stopPlayback();
    }
};
```

Then you can call this by:

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
```

The code within `task` will execute 5 seconds after calling `handler.postDelayed()`

I would suggest you get a `VideoView` working normally, then add your handler.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly look up foreground vs background android docs and how activities work in general. You wont need any sort of handler for video views to work. Video views are views.

Then look at what handlers are and how they work here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

For your task - Write a separate handler in your activity that is responsible for your videoview like so - basically listen for time as the video plays and then pop up once the played time matches the time where you want to pop up the toast.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
...
handler.post(timefortoast);
....

int curVideoPosition;
    private final Runnable timefortoast= new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (video.isPlaying()) {
                    cumulativeTimeSpent += 1;
                }

                // prepare and send the data here..
                curVideoPosition = video.getCurrentPosition();
//Match cumulative time spent and curvideoposition to pop up whatever you want, toast or whatever in the middle of the video
```

and then detach the callback in `ondestroy`

```
handler.removeCallbacks(timefortoast);
```